# How to insert a clickable link into each td in php

Tags: php, html

I'm working with a row of html table cells that look like:

```
<td align="left" class="info">my message goes here</td>
<td align="left" class="info">my message goes here</td>
```

I would like to modify these cells by inserting a clickable anchor tag into each.

I have written the following function:

```
public function modifyAttribute2($domDoc) {


            //We use xpath to search ChildElement:
            $domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDoc);

            $items = $domXPath->query("//td[@class='moreinfo']");

       foreach ($items as $item) {
                echo $item->nodeValue . "\n";
                $item->nodeValue = "hi";

                $doc = new DOMDocument();

                $valid_elem = $doc->createElement('a');
                $valid_attr = $doc->createAttribute('href');
                $valid_attr->value = base_url();
                $valid_elem->appendChild($valid_attr);

                // We insert the new element as root (child of the document)
                $xmlcontent = $domDoc->importNode($valid_elem, true);                  
                $item->appendChild($xmlcontent);                
                $domDoc->saveXML($item);                }


            echo $domDoc->saveXML();
            exit;

     }
```

addendum:

I'm trying to create and import a new domdocument node into my original document $domDoc as suggested but I do not see any sign of the imported node after saving and inspecting the html. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PHP DOM isn't like jquery where you can insert arbitrary html strings and have it rebuild the DOM for you. You need to do `$domDoc->createElement('a')`, set its values/attributes, then `->appendChild()` it.

Comment: do you ->appendChild() it to the td ?

Comment: I've edited the original question.

Comment: do you have to use php for this? and where is the markup coming from?